# Restlet returning 422 with Post("xml") to DomRepresentation

Tags: java, xml, restlet

I'm using a Resetlet ServerResource in a Restlet EE Application to handle an XML post. If I annotate with @Post and take a Representation parameter, both text/xml and application/xml are accepted. Even if change the annotation to @Post("xml") both types are accepted. If I change the parameter to a DomRepresentation then application/xml is rejected with a 422 status code and the message:

> The server understands the content type of the request entity and the syntax of the request entity is correct but was unable to process the contained instructions

I am testing with Postman and simply changing the Body type between raw XML(application/xml) and XML(text/xml). The [documentation appears to indicate](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/user-guide/2.3/core/services/converter) that org.restlet.ext.xml.DomRepresentation handles APPLICATION_ALL_XML, APPLICATION_XML, and TEXT_XML.

What am I missing?

This is OK for both:

```
@Post
public Representation doPost(Representation entity) {
    return entity;
}
```

So is this:

```
@Post("xml")
public Representation doPostXml(Representation entity) {
    return entity;
}
```

Returns 422:

```
@Post("xml")
public Representation doPostXml(DomRepresentation entity) {
    return entity;
}
```

The DomRepresentation will accept an xml document when posted as type text, text/plain, text/xml, and text/html, but not as application/xml.

I tried XmlRepresentation.

```
@Post
public Representation doPost(XmlRepresentation entity) {
    return entity;
}
```

It fails with a 422 for text/xml and application/xml. With text it returns 415 and this message:

> The server is refusing to service the request because the entity of the request is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Restlet EE 2.3.12 from maven.restlet.com hosted in a Tomcat 8.5 container using Java 1.8.

Comment: Can you please try: `org.restlet.ext.xml.XmlRepresentation` instead of `org.restlet.ext.xml.DomRepresentation` and update whether you are getting the same error or not?

Comment: @AbhishekOza, with XmlRepresentation it fails on both text/xml and application/xml.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample i am presenting. Please compare it with your code and HTTP request and see what is missing.

Environment: JDK 1.8
Compiler level: Java 1.7
Jar files: (1) org.restlet.ext.xml.jar (2) org.restlet.jar

Following is the sample code and HTTP request i have tried and run successfully.

Code:

```
package com.arzoo.resources;

import org.restlet.Server;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.ext.xml.DomRepresentation;
import org.restlet.representation.Representation;
import org.restlet.resource.Post;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class TestXml extends ServerResource
{   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   // Create the HTTP server and listen on port 8182
        new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8182, TestXml.class).start();
    }

    @Post("xml")
    public Representation doPostXml(DomRepresentation entity)
    {   return entity;
    }
}
```

HTTP request from command line:

```
~$ curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/xml" "http://localhost:8182" -d "<MyRoot/>"
```

HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.3.12
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2018 12:06:28 GMT
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-type: application/xml
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><MyRoot/>
```

Comment: This appears to work the same for me. I copied the restlet-version, maven-restlet repository, and artifactIds for org.restlet.jee's org.restlet and org.restlet.ext.xml from my tomcat restlet project to this sample jse project (even though it only needed the jsa ones). The main difference seems to be running it in a Tomcat container. I will keep looking. Thanks.